# How to get information form a prompt and print it to the screen in Genexus

Tags: panel, prompt, genexus

I have this web panel right here [image] and this prompt pop up after clicking the arrow[image], how can I get the information from the prompt and print to the screen. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you want to accomplish. Based on the printscreen you are using the standard automatically generated [Prompt object](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21635,Prompt,) on a [Foreign Key](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?23894,Selection%20Lists). The popup will select the value and return and assign on the caller the selection. Then, based on ajax when transitioning between fields will get secondary attributes values based on that selection (if any).
You could use a custom prompt with a [rule](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6863,Prompt%20rule) and change the out parameters to receive more information on the caller. Other option would be to use [other events](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?24271,Category%3AControl%20Events) on that field (ControlValueChanged/IsValid?) and add some coding.
hope it helps